# How install Nuget Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu for ONNX Runtime in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: nuget, ubuntu-18.04, onnxruntime

I'm trying to use ONNX runtime for Ubuntu: https://onnxruntime.ai/

I selected Linux, C++, x64, then CUDA. It says "Install Nuget package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu
Refer to docs for requirements."

When I click on "Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu", I'm taken to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu

There, it just says "Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu -Version 1.8.1". Now what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

They expect you to install nuget in linux with

`sudo apt-get install -y nuget`

And then run the following with the version you want installed.

`nuget install Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Gpu -Version 1.12.0`

That's the expected approach.  Personally, for me that didn't work.  I kept getting some error saying "'Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Managed' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Memory'."  So I did it a different way.  I just went to https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/tag/v1.12.0.  And then at the bottom under assets it lists pre-built .tgz packages for the different setups.  You can just download one and unpack it.